# using jquery position() with div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var x = document.getElementById("testingAjax");
    if (x != null) {
        var left = x.position().left;
        alert(left);
    }
```

why is the above code breaking? It is breaking on `var left = x.position().left` with the error **Object doesn't support this property or method;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you need to wrap any non jQuery object in $(..). So your code becomes:

```
var x = document.getElementById("testingAjax");
if (x != null) {
    var left = $(x).position().left; // x by itself is not a jQuery object. Need to pass it to $(..)
    alert(left);
}
```